A novel with a girl who could command living things, even causing them to die
This is story I vaguely remember. I probably read it at least 15 years ago.
One of the main characters in the story is a young girl who has the ability to command living things to do what she wants. I believe it is phrased as something along the lines of "she says what she wants, and the things that hear her want to comply". A scene I remember is either her recalling, or being told, that as a child she had ordered plants and trees to flower during the winter. She was then told that the plants died shortly after because they used too much energy to survive the rest of the season.
Other things I recall/think I recall:

The setting is a medieval fantasy
She has a brother. I believe he also had powers but they were different or manifested later.
Their powers were due to their ancestry, which may not have been human. I believe they are orphans at the time of the story
For a good part of the story, she is being escorted somewhere by another character. She may not have been entirely willing to go along.
Her power can also affect people. This definitely happens in the story, though I don't remember any particular scenes.


Sounds a bit like Kahlan's powers in Wizard's First Rule, though she didn't have a brother and wasn't able to control plants and flowers.

@AJM I don't think the effect was permanent like a confessor's touch. I also don't think the power was man/wizard-made.

I think there's a TVTropes page for this kind of power set, but I'm at work at the moment and can't look it up. I reckon if you check the Dune entry, there should be a link to it as the Bene Gesserit Voice was an example of it.
